# Error in mapping one-to-many with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapper, has-many

I am new to NHibernate and C#, so please be gentle!

I have the following two NHibernate entities:

```
public class Client : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Residence> Residences { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class Residence : IEntity
{
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual int ClientId { get; set; }

     public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

and they have a one-to-many relationship from Client to Residence(each client can have multiple residence in their record).

Have this mappings with use automapping

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Client> mapping)
{
     mapping.Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
     mapping.HasMany(c => c.Residences).KeyColumn("Id").Inverse().Cascade.All();
     mapping.Table("Clients");
}
```

and

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Residence> mapping)
{
     mapping.Id(p => p.Id);
     mapping.References(x => x.Client).Column("Id").Not.Nullable().Cascade.All();
     mapping.Table("Residences");
}
```

In my controller call IRepository of Client:

```
ClientModel newClient = ClientModel;

Client DomainModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(newClient, new Client());

_clientService.Create(DomainModel);
```

Repository:

```
public class ClientService : IClientService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Client> _clientRepository;

    public void Create(Client client)
    {
        _clientRepository.Create(client);
    }
}
```

I have a problem with use Foreign key to Client.

This error: NHibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value ProjectBase.Domain.Entities.Residence.Client

I think this is because you try to use the ForeignKey Id Client that is not yet added to the table Client. But I do not know how to solve it. I need Help solved this error. Thank!

Comment: Does the `client` you're persisting have any `residence`s? Somewhere, NH has a `residence` in its unit of work that it's trying to save but it has a null `client`.

Comment: yes, i have 1 or more Residence in Client when it gives the error.

Comment: Do the residence(s) have their `Client` property set to the parent client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, changed mapping to:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Client> mapping)
{
     mapping.Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
     mapping.HasMany(c => c.Residences).Inverse().Cascade.All();
     mapping.Table("Clients");
}

and

public void Override(AutoMapping<Residence> mapping)
{
     mapping.Id(p => p.Id);
     mapping.References(x => x.Client)
}
```

and add constructor in Clients

```
public Client()
{
    Residences = new List<Residence>();
}
```

Ty.